# Trying to display a cv2 QRcode scanner within tkinter (python)

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter

I'm trying to make show a QRcode scanner within a tkinter frame by packing a label and configuring it to the image the camera sees each time an image is retrieved. I currently don't know why the tkinter window UI is not being displayed while the openQRScanner subroutine is running. could it be a problem caused by the imageStorer.after line?

```
#this is a frame that is in a window
#The UI frame for the main menu
class menuFrame(dataEntryFrame):

     def createFrame(self,parent):

        self.__button = tk.Button(self, command = lambda: parent.raiseFrame(parent.datFrame, "datFrame"), height = 0, width = 8, text = "Sign Up", font = ("",35))
        self.__button.pack(pady = 10)

        self.cameraSize = (winPix[0],winPix[1])
        self.camera = tk.Label(self, width = self.cameraSize[0], height = self.cameraSize[1])
        self.camera.pack(pady = 10)
        qrcodescanNmake.openQRScanner(self.camera, parent, self.cameraSize)
        
            
        self.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "news")
```

This is the code for the openQRScanner within the qrcodescanNmake file, I commented out the decoding part and am focusing on the displaying the video part but I do hope that the data decoded can be stored in a variable in the UI code file

```
#qrcode scanner to retrieve customer id from the customer 
def openQRScanner(imageStorer,clsParent,dimensions):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    #sets the size for the camera
    cam.set(3,dimensions[0])
    cam.set(4,dimensions[1])

    #stop = False

    
    successRet,img = cam.read()
        
    #sets the image within the frame to the image that the camera sees
    rgbimg = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    rgbimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rgbimg)
    imageStorer.config(image = rgbimg)
    imageStorer.after(10, openQRScanner(imageStorer,clsParent,dimensions))
        #retrieves data from the qrcode and returns it
        #if successRet:
         #   for code in decode(img):
          #      try:
           #         data = code.data.decode("utf-8")
            #        data = int(data)
             #       #classParent.raiseFrame()
              #      return data
               # except:
                #    print("fail scan")
                 #   pass
        #check if menuFrame is still on top if not stop scanner
```

removing the imageStorer.after line allows the UI window to be displayed but only the "Next" button would be shown and no image would be displayed on the label, after that by moving the self.camera.pack(pady = 10) line to run after the scanner changed the image once would change nothing aswell

Comment: maybe you have old problem with `bug` in `PhotoImage` - `garbage collector` removes image from memory when you assign to local variable in function. And later you can't see this image. You have to assign to global variable  - it needs `global rgbimg` - or you have to assign to other object  - ie. `imageStorer.rgbimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rgbimg)`

Comment: `after` (similar to `command=` in `Button`) needs `callback` - it means `function's name without () and without arguments` - and later it will use `()` to execute it. To send arguments you can add them at the end of `after()` - `after(10, openQRScanner, imageStorer, clsParent,dimensions)`. Eventually you can use `lambda` like `after(10, lambda:openQRScanner(imageStorer, clsParent,dimensions) )`

Answer (score 0):

I can't run it but I see two possible problems.

1. **after**

`after` (similar to `command=` in `Button`) needs `callback`. It means `function's name without () and without arguments`. It will later use `()` to execute it. Problem are arguments.

To send arguments you can add them at the end of `after()`

```
after(10, openQRScanner, imageStorer, clsParent, dimensions)
```

Eventually you can use `lambda` like

```
after(10, lambda:openQRScanner(imageStorer, clsParent, dimensions) )
```

2. **PhotoImage**

There is  `bug` in `PhotoImage` - `garbage collector` removes image from memory when you assign to local variable in function. And later you can't see this image.

You have to assign to `global` variable

```
def openQRScanner(imageStorer,clsParent,dimensions):

    global rgbimg

    # ... 

    rgbimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rgbimg)
```

or you can assign to other object - ie.

```
def openQRScanner(imageStorer,clsParent,dimensions):

    # ...

    rgbimg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(rgbimg)

    imageStorer.rgbimg = rgbimg
```

---

See doc: [The Tkinter PhotoImage Class](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)